# How to count unique records in a column that have a value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, counting

I have this issue: here is my table

```
ColA  ColB      
te     Y
te     Y
alo    
te     Y
te     
bb     Y
aa     Y
```

I want to count how many records in ColA, which has value "Y" in Col B. and if two duplicate record in A that also have same Y then just count one. (in this case, te record we just count one time)
Many thanks

Comment: thanks DanM for editing, now it is nicer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure is there is a simple formula to achieve what you want, though it may be possible with an array formula of some kind.

The simplest way in my view would be:

1. Select your data
2. Select **Data > Filter > Advanced Filter**
3. Check the **Unique Records Only** checkbox
4. Select a range you would like to copy the results to in **Copy to**
5. Now hit **OK**
6. Now use `=COUNTIF` with criteria **=Y** to get number of unique records that also have Y

---

**Edit - Array Formula Solution**

I did some googling and found a site that shows how to return unique rows using an array formula. [See here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/02/03/how-to-count-unique-combined-column-values/).

We can use that to return **all** unique rows in your rows in columns A and B, including rows where column B is blank. (I assume your data is in cell A2:B8)

```
=SUM(IF(((MATCH(A2:A8&B2:B8,A2:A8&B2:B8,0)) >=(ROW(A2:A8)-(MIN(ROW(A2:A8))-1)))=TRUE,1,0))
```

Once we know the total number of unique rows, if we subtract from that number the cells in column B that are blank (i.e. not equal to Y) then this should give us the total number of unique rows that have a Y in column B. We can now update the above formula as follows:

```
=SUM(IF(((MATCH(A2:A8&B2:B8,A2:A8&B2:B8,0)) >=(ROW(A2:A8)-(MIN(ROW(A2:A8))-1)))=TRUE,1,0)) - COUNTIF(B2:B8,"<>Y")
```

Type this formula in `C1` and then press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` as this is an array formula.

I tested this and it seemed to work ok.

Comment: thanks for this, but what if I can have a formula, as the sheet will update many time but many users, then it cannot auto run.

Comment: hic, I try this, it seem to work fine until another testcase then the resutl is wrong: let' say the table not like this:                                                                   ColA     ColB      
    te     Y
    te     
    alo    
    te     
    te     
    bb                                                              
    aa     Y
noe te: has one Y and 3 value :none, then the result only 1, as the count for value not Y is 4. so the resutl not correct any more :(